# Django-Sorting-Bootstrap Heroku push failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, pip

I'm deploying a django project with django-sorting-bootstrap on heroku and I'm having some trouble.

Here's my error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-sorting-bootstrap==2.6.2 
(from -r (my folder)/requirements.txt (line 65)) (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.1.1)
```

Any idea why the versions only go up to 1.1.1 when the latest release is 2.62?

Comment: Post your `runtime.txt` please. You might be using Python 2.x.

Comment: @Selcuk  python version Python 3.8.5, (checking with python -V)

Comment: I am talking about the Python version installed on Heroku. Do you have a `runtime.txt`? If not, the default version is Python 3.6: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version

Comment: I didn't have a runtime.txt, i added one with my python version in an effort to override the behaviour though, seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your virtualenv and Heroku are both using the same version of python.

In command prompt / terminal, run this to get the python version on heroku:

```
heroku run python --version
```

and on your computer:

```sh
python --version
```

If they are different versions, change the version `django-sorting-bootstrap` to an older version in requirements.txt.

Comment: I ended up setting a runtime.txt and deleted the deprecated packages, not much of a solution but it sort of worked